# What are normal checksum

Tags: shell, cmd, checksum

## Part one of question

On my server I am compressing all my files.
I am trying to put the original file/folder checksum on my records
What are the normal checksum for file and folders?
I think that md5 is and the others are?

### added for clarification

I will be using more than one sumcheck. 3 or 5 avenues of sumcheck
Is there a standard for how to store sumcheck in a files for an app to uses later to verification a file
what are the different avenues of sumcheck types
so md* is one avenues and sha* is another one
So is md5 ok

I have 20TB SAN for storage, but the largest file I can store right now is 2gb. but I have good file version control.
I would reformat the drive but I do not have that level control on file system I just have control what files and folder to storing it.
eventually I will have full control and then I will put a custom file system on the SAN.
for now I am  compressing *.ios of OS and splitting file up and compressing my projects so when I need to work on them I have a 1TB SSD I use for my active projects.
so I just push the whole projects folder to the san storage, when I send it I compress and split.. but I like to some check compress sumcheck compress file then push it to SAN. When I need projects or ISO A pull it from the SAN and put on the SSD

for processing power I have AMD Opteron 6348 Abu Dhabi 2.8GHz 12MB L2 Cache 16MB L3 Cache Socket G34 115W 12-Core Server Processor OS6348WKTCGHKWOF that should be good for a while.

### in folder checksum

so if I will be checksum all file then how to put the contact of the folder together so I have a value for the data in folder

## Part two of question

lightweight portable and installed app to use in ms windows from command line?
lightweight portable and installed app to use in Linux Ubuntu from command line?

## part two and a half of question

is it easer to make a sumcheck app or interface with already done ones?

Comment: added text added for clarification

Comment: add part two and half

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows:

```
fsum SlavaSoft Inc.
```

and fastsum

```
FastSum - extremely fast utility for your files integrity control. FastSum calculates short and strong digests of your data via popular MD5 algorithm to use it as references checksums for ulterior data integrity verification. 

FastSum - Allows to rectify the errors occurring while data transfer. For example: Network transfers, CD-R and DVD burning and much more. It is developed for easy processing of a huge files count and has usable command-line interface. It is an analogue of a famous md5sum Unix platform utility.
```

and MD5sums

```
MD5sums is win32 command line software to generate MD5 hashes of files
```

Answer (score 0):

**Part one:**

`md5sum` is widely used for file checksum. it is reported that, md5sum has its weakness. 
There are other alternatives:

```
sha1sum or sha224sum sha256sum sha384sum sha512sum ...
```

all above tool could compute checksum of a file, a string, but not directly on a directory. They are for files. You can generate all files under a directory recursively.

**Part two:**

Sorry I don't understand what you want to ask. the two sentences are ending with question marks, but after I read them, they are not questions at all.

Comment: It's not just a weakness, MD5 as a cryptographic hash algorithm is [broken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), and [so is SHA-1](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html). However, depending on the scenario MD5 may still be useful in some cases (see the answers to [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/15790) on IT Security).

Comment: I use another app for cryptographic in security I'm just checking the contest of data.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the normal checksum for file and folders?

Normally, in isolation, the term 'checksum' refers to the value generated for a given file. The point is that the checksum value is sufficiently unique to detect changes in the data, hence ideally no 2 files with different content should have the same 'checksum'. If you mean what checksum *alogrithm* you use, then it depends on how strictly you want to enforce integrity, how much overhead you can afford in terms of bandiwdth / storage and computation time.

If you are putting all the files into an archive, then you only need to verify the checksum of the archive , not individual files. But if there's a chance that the data will be modified then using checksums for each file might be a good idea.

In addition to considering which algorithm to use, you also need to consider how you use it. If you want to protect against malicious interference then you need a hash function (a cryptographically strong subset of checksum algorithms) and should use it with a secret random value either prepended or appended to the data).

```
checksum=f(contents_of_file, secret_string);
```

No doubt someone will be along shortly to say that md5 is insecure. That's not the case. It's less secure than other methods, but more secure then a lot of other methods. The level of difficulty for reversing an md5 hash has decreased over time because people have found better ways of attacking it.

There are lots of checksum methods:

parity check - easily faked - only detects odd numbers of bit-flips in the data

[cyclic redundancy check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)  - again easily faked, but very low processing overhead

sha-1 - similar to md5 but with extra rounds of hashing resulting in a larger but mre secure digest

sha-256 - same again but more secure.

For Linux, md5sum comes with the GNU coreutils package (hence will run on MSWindows with Cygwin) nd there are [native MSWindowsNT tools](http://www.openoffice.org/dev_docs/using_md5sums.html).

Comment: so MD5 to MD255 more secure and sha1 to sha256 more md255<br />
so for three standers use SH6 sha256 ?

Comment: from MD5 to MD255 more MD255 is more secure and sha1 to sha256 more sha256<br />
so for three standers to use probably SH6 sha256 ?
or just do all checksums